# mySQL return specific rows per field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to try my best to explain this... I'm looking to get 5 random rows to return for each field. For example, I have:

```html
SELECT "Name","Ticket ID","Channel"
FROM Tickets
  WHERE "Ticket Created at" between date('2017-09-01') AND date('2017-10-01')
  AND "Channel" = 'Phone' or 'Chat' or 'Email'
  AND "First Agent Primary Email" = 'abc.def@mail.com'
```

And what I want to do is for the table to return 5 random ticket IDs per phone channel, per chat channel or per email channel.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers all seemed to have problems with their date range, as did your original query, so I decided to post this:

```
SELECT
    Name, `Ticket ID`, Channel
FROM Tickets
WHERE 
    `Ticket Created at` >= '2017-09-01' AND `Ticket Created at` < '2017-10-01' AND
    Channel IN ('Phone', 'Chat', 'Email') AND
    `First Agent Primary Email` = 'abc.def@mail.com'
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT 5;
```

The critical thing is that if you want restrict to the month of September, you need to phrase it carefully when using date literals.  The following is a trap which is to be avoided:

```
WHERE `Ticket Created at` BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'
```

This will possibly include data which happens to fall on midnight of October 1, probably not what you have in mind.  And also, you don't need to wrap date literals with `DATE`; MySQL can already handle them if in the right format (you used the right format).

**Edit:**

If you want 5 random tickets for each of the three channels, you can do so with a union query:

```
SELECT Name, `Ticket ID`, Channel
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, `Ticket ID`, Channel
    FROM Tickets
    WHERE `Ticket Created at` >= '2017-09-01' AND
          `Ticket Created at` < '2017-10-01' AND
          Channel = 'Phone' AND
         `First Agent Primary Email` = 'abc.def@mail.com'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
) t1
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT Name, `Ticket ID`, Channel
    FROM Tickets
    WHERE `Ticket Created at` >= '2017-09-01' AND
          `Ticket Created at` < '2017-10-01' AND
          Channel = 'Chat' AND
         `First Agent Primary Email` = 'abc.def@mail.com'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
) t2
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT Name, `Ticket ID`, Channel
    FROM Tickets
    WHERE `Ticket Created at` >= '2017-09-01' AND
          `Ticket Created at` < '2017-10-01' AND
          Channel = 'Email' AND
         `First Agent Primary Email` = 'abc.def@mail.com'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
) t3;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! If I'm looking for the database to return 5 ticket IDs for each channel, so 5 ticket IDs for phone, 5 ticket IDs for chat and 5 ticket IDs for email, how would I go about that?

Comment: @AJT You just asked for a completely different query.  How do we know you won't change your requirement a third time?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but my original question was "I want to do is for the table to return 5 random ticket IDs *per* phone channel, per chat channel or per email channel." Ex: 5 random IDs for phone, 5 for chat, 5 for email.

Comment: @AJT My fault...I looked at the other answers and assumed they had read correctly.  I updated with one approach, which is to use a union of three subqueries.

Comment: That update really helped me out. Appreciated that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

```
SELECT Name,Ticket ID,Channel FROM Tickets
WHERE Ticket Created at between date('2017-09-01') 
AND date('2017-10 
01')
AND Channel IN ( 'Phone', 'Chat' , 'Email')
AND First Agent Primary Email = 'abc.def@mail.com'
ORDER BY  RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for something like this:

```html
SELECT "Name","Ticket ID","Channel"
FROM Tickets
  WHERE "Ticket Created at" between date('2017-09-01') AND date('2017-10-01')
  AND "Channel" = 'Phone' or 'Chat' or 'Email'
  AND "First Agent Primary Email" = 'abc.def@mail.com'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

as you can see i added the line `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5` which orders the rows randomly and returns the first 5.

Comment: There are no built in code snippets for SQL on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

your probably need that:

```
SELECT "Name","Ticket ID","Channel"
FROM Tickets
WHERE "Ticket Created at" between date('2017-09-01') AND date('2017-10-01')
AND ( "Channel" = 'Phone' or "Channel" = 'Chat' or "Channel" = 'Email' )
AND "First Agent Primary Email" = 'abc.def@mail.com'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quote for columns name  .. when you have composite name use backtics
  use IN clause for several value (or repeat the column name for each or condition)
  and you can use limit 5 and order by rand() for get 5  casual row

```
  SELECT Name,`Ticket ID`,Channel
  FROM Tickets
  WHERE `Ticket Created at` between date('2017-09-01') AND date('2017-10-01')
  AND `Channel` IN ( 'Phone', 'Chat' , 'Email')
  AND `First Agent Primary Email` = 'abc.def@mail.com'
  ORDER BY order by rand() limit 5
```